Voltage difference?
I read that voltage is simply measuring the difference between two points like a water meter (it measures the difference between the water pressure and atmospheric pressure). So, according to that, if you connect one lead to a battery's positive and another's positive, the voltmeter should read the difference between the batteries:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
But, it doesn't do anything. So what is going on here? Is it because the electrons don't have anywhere to go?

A water meter measures volumetric flow.

" Is it because the electrons don't have anywhere to go?" - Actually, yes.

A water pressure gauge may indeed be measuring the pressure difference between the atmosphere and some place in the water system, but the atmosphere has roughly the same pressure at all points in space, giving the impression that you don't need to "close the circuit". Two pressure gauges even several meters apart will still have access to the same atmospheric pressure, with which to "calculate" the difference.
In an electrical system, to ensure that two points in a circuit have the same electrical potential, you must physically connect them together:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The lower red wire is needed to ensure that the negative terminals of each voltage source have the same potential. Only then do both upper battery terminals have well defined potentials with respect to each other, the difference between which can be displayed on the voltmeter.

If you are wondering, the triangular ground symbol is just telling the simulator to treat that node as "zero volts", necessary for all other nodes in the circuit to have meaningful "absolute" potentials with respect to this zero reference. That triangle is purely symbolic; in real electrical systems there's no absolute "zero volt" point, all that exists are potential differences.
Having a zero reference is for algebraic convenience only. That node could be +1000V for all we know, and the battery positives would then be +1009V and +1006V respectively, still having a difference of 3V. The circuit would function no differently. However, you'd still need a wire to join the battery negatives, ensuring that their potentials are equal.

To get back to the water pressure analogy, remember that the only reason atmospheric pressure is equal at all points in air-space is that when there is a pressure difference in that space, air molecules are free to move, and will move in whatever direction is necessary to eventually equalise pressure everywhere, cancelling the pressure difference. This is why you you don't need to explicitly connect the "atmosphere" side of water pressure gauges; they are all implicitly connected by space in which air can self-equalise in pressure.
This is not the case for electric charges, like electrons. Charges are unable to move freely except in conductive mediums, of which air is not one. That's why you have to join nodes of a circuit with a good electrical conductor, in which charges are free to move, in order for two nodes to be brought to the same potential, or electrical "pressure".

The negative terminals must be at the same potential in order for this to work. In other words, you need to connect the negatives and thereby complete the circuit. If the negatives aren't connected, the potential difference between the batteries is not defined as they don't share a common reference potential, so you can't meaningfully measure a voltage between them.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
As you can see, it works just like you described once you add the missing connection.
